# Как во vue-cli3 сделать build с корректными url?

Tags: vue.js

После билда проекта хотелось бы видеть статик файлы в /static/dist/, для этого использую baseUrl: "/static/dist/', в таком случае заходя на главную страницу вместо адреса 'localhost/' я получаю 'localhost/static/dist/', и все пути строятся соответственно относительно этого. мой файл vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: '/static/dist/',
  outputDir: '../api/static/dist/',
}
```

Пробовал делать build с конфиг файлом config/index.js

```
build: { 
    assetsPublicPath: '/', 
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
  },
```

Но при билде вью не видит этот конфиг файл. Каким образом можно настроить относительные пути для статики при этом используя роутинг относительно '/' а не того что прописано в baseUrl?

Comment: Используйте [`outputDir`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#outputdir) и [`assetsDir`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#assetsdir) вместо `baseUrl`